# A code from a TikZ-CD manual is not compiling

Tags: tikz-cd

Here is the code from page 2 in a `TikZ-CD` manual found [here](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf). I loaded `\usetikzlibrary{cd}`, and I loaded `quotes`.  (Immediately preceding this example, it says "labels can be placed on an arrow by means of the quotes syntax.")  Why is the following code not compiling?  How do I add `\psi` to the other arrow?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}

A \arrow[rd] \arrow[r, "\phi"] &B \\
&C

\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What TeX distribution are you running? It works for me, provided I remove the blank lines in the `tikzcd` environment that are not allowed.

Comment: Compiles just fine for me too – after removing the blank lines. To add `\psi` to the other arrow replace `\arrow[rd]` with `\arrow[rd, "\psi"]`

Comment: @ egreg  I removed the blank lines.  It does not compile.  I got the error message "1.4 \usetikzlibrary{cd}". I am using WinEdt 8.1 .

Comment: @JBantje  If this is similar to a environment for matrices, shouldn't there be two "&"?  The first column is for "A," the second column is for the arrows, and the third column is for "B."

Comment: The matrix-syntax is just for the nodes. The `\arrow` commands are placed in the cell they are starting at. Their target is determined by _walking trough the matrix_. In this case `right` and  `down` for the first arrow. The author of the package decided not to separate the "specify the nodes" and "specify the arrows" tasks in code… (and I'm fine with that)

Comment: @Adelyn Do you still have this error? Which version of Ti*k*Z and `tikz-cd` do you have?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi  The code does not compile on my computer.  How do I determine which version of `TikZ` that I have on my computer?

Comment: @JBantje   I forgot what the code should get `TikZ` to display; so, I don't remember whether there is one arrow in the diagram or there are two arrows.  How do I know from the code that the arrow is either pointing southeast or there are two arrows, one pointing eastward and one pointing southward?